# How to do MongoDB retry in nest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nest

I'm trying to write retry mongoDB in a nest

I'm trying to write retry mongoDB in a nest
I did this: retryAttempts: Infinity,
And it works when the backend is up and the mongoDB is down but the retry doesn't work when the backend and the mongoDB is up and after x time mongoDB is down, how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.